# Cannot send email with attachments programmatically via Gmail

Tags: android, gmail, android-support-library

I'm developing an Android application which composes an email with photo attachments and sends it via 3rd party application.

To compose email programmatically I use `IntentBuilder` class.

```
/**
 * Helpers to compose and send emails with 3rd party apps.
 */
public final class MailUtils {

    /**
     * Creates {@link Intent} and fills data to send email with 3rd party application.
     *
     * @param activity
     * @param photoUris list of photo URIs which can be accessed with {@link android.support.v4.content.FileProvider}
     * @param requestCode to filter results in {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)}
     */
    public static void sendMail(Activity activity, List<Uri> photoUris, int requestCode) {
        final ShareCompat.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
                .setType("text/html")
                .setChooserTitle("Choose application to send email")
                .addEmailTo("someone@anywhere.com")
                .addEmailCc("someone.else@anywhere.com")
                .setSubject("This is subject")
                .setHtmlText("Hello, world!");
        if (photoUris != null) {
            for (Uri photoUri : photoUris) {
                intentBuilder.addStream(photoUri); // add photo attachment
            }
        }
        if (activity.getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intentBuilder.getIntent(), 0) != null) {
            final Intent intent = intentBuilder.createChooserIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Email app not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error notification**

[image: Couln't send attachment error]

Gmail only sends email text, but skips attachments. The issue persists only with **Gmail** Android app. Everything works properly with other email apps (e.g. **Outlook** and **Yahoo**).

**Note:** size of photo attachments in my cases usually less than 10MB.

For workaround I tried to compress photos in single ZIP archive, but results was almost the same. It worked for 5-10 zipped photos, but couln't work for more than 10 photos.

**Tested on devices**

- LG Nexus 4 (Jelly Bean `4.2.2`, Gmail `6.11.27...`)
- LG Nexus 5X (Nougat `7.1.2`, Gmail `7.3.26...`)
- Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (Marshmallow `6.0.1`, Gmail `7.3.26...`)

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find any solution? Regards from Berlin, Germany

Comment: @RicoHerlt Yes, I found workaround. Initially I used `FileProvider` to attach photos from app directory (located at `context.getFilesDir()` or `context.getCacheDir()`). Now all photos stored in device's gallery and I use it's URIs when building an `Intent`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here, as mentioned by the OP in a comment, is to use a FileProvider to temporarily grant access to the files to be attached. Details can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html.

I also found this tutorial helpful: https://drivy.engineering/android-fileprovider/.

Answer (score -2):

When you attach the file it takes some time to attach with mail so for that you have to perform your operation with AsyncTask.Try this code it works with Gmail and works with 7.0 os too.

```
private class attachMailProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        // Progress visibility Visible
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... param)
    {
        YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                File file = // Get your file here.
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("message/rfc822");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"Your email"});
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your body text");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Email Chooser"));
                        // Progress visibility gone
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        // Progress visibility gone
                        Toast.makeText(NewRoundActivity.this, "No Email client found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    //File not found
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Progress visibility gone
    }
}
```